# Combining a stream of multiple XML documents into a single valid document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file which I am trying to edit.   The file was developed poorly, and as a result, contains multiple namespace declarations and closing root tags throughout the document.   Is there anyway to strip these extra namespaces and closing tags and only leave the 1 namespace at the top of the file and 1 closing tag at the bottom?

Below is a simplified version of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:demographic xmlns:p="http://crown.esrd.net/crown"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://crown.esrd.net/crown crown.xsd">
<patient>
<lastName>JOHNS</lastName>
<firstName>JASON</firstName>
<middleInitial>Y</middleInitial>
</patient>
</p:demographic>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:demographic xmlns:p="http://crown.esrd.net/crown"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://crown.esrd.net/crown crown.xsd">
<patient>
<lastName>CALDWELL</lastName>
<firstName>PENNY</firstName>
<middleInitial>Y</middleInitial>
</patient>
</p:demographic>
```

Comment: This input actually _isn't_ a valid XML file, making the question title a bit misleading. Edited.

Comment: ...also, because the input isn't a valid document, this can't be done with XSLT (or, can't be done with XSLT alone). Is there a reason you tagged your question as "xslt"?

Comment: Here's the thing -- doing this in a way that's guaranteed to be correct (for instance, leave alone any `<?xml ...?>` strings quoted inside a `CDATA` section) is _hard_. In fact, if I were going to do it, I'd probably use a real XML parser, record the file offsets at which it detects each error, seek to below them and rerun to identify the fragment offsets, feed each fragment through, combine them... the output would be guaranteed correct, unlike the more naive approaches, but it's also more work than I'm going to do for an answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what you've posted.
Just use a text editor to chop out all but the first xml directive.
Add a root node start tag, add the namespace to it
Tear the rest of them out and and add a closing root tag.

Bob's your mother's sister's brother.

Writing a bit of code to do the this if you have a few of them, shouldn't be too hard.